# Using OS.walk and paramiko to move files to ftp server causing EOFError?

Tags: python-2.7, ftp, paramiko, os.walk

My goal is to walk through all files in a folder (and subfolders), check whether the file already exists on the ftp.  If the file doesn't exist, put in in destination folder and if it does exist, archive the old file using rename and put the new file in it's place.  My code so far is as follows.

```
path = 'Z:\\_MAGENTO IMAGES\\2014\\Jun2014\\09Jun2014'
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()  
log_file = 'C:\\Temp\\log.txt'
paramiko.util.log_to_file(log_file)    
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())



def upload_images():




    #' #In case the server's key is unknown,'
    #we will be adding it automatically to the list of known hosts 
    #ssh.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser(os.path.join("~", ".ssh", "known_hosts")))   

    #Loads the user's local known host file  
    ssh.connect('xxxxxxxxxxxxx', port=22,     username='xxxxxxxx', password='xxxxxxxxx') 
    ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command('ls /tmp') 
    print "output", ssh_stdout.read() #Reading output of the executed co'mmand 
error = ssh_stderr.read()  

    #Reading the error stream of the executed command
    print "err", error, len(error) 

    #Transfering files to and from the remote machine' 
    sftp = ssh.open_sftp()   
    #'sftp.get(remote_path, local_path)' 

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for fn in files:
            ftp_path = '/productimages/' + fn
            archive = '/productimages/archive/' + fn
            source = root + '\\' + fn
            try:
                sftp.stat(ftp_path)
            except IOError as e:
                print e.errno
                print errno.ENOENT
                if e.errno == errno.ENOENT:
                    print 'this is if'
                    sftp.put(source, ftp_path)

            else:
                print 'this is else'
                sftp.rename(ftp_path,archive)
                sftp.put(root + '\\' + fn, ftp_path)

            finally:
                sftp.close()
                ssh.close() 
            #update_log()
```

What happens.  If the file doesn't exist I get an EOFerror.  I'll have to set some conditions for the situation if the file is already archived but I will cross that bridge when I get to it.  I am being really thick and can't tease out the issues.  Any thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The `EOFError` occurs because of misplaced `finally` clause: `sftp` and `ssh` are closed after first processed file.

The second problem is that `sftp.rename(ftp_path,archive)` will fail if `archive` file exists.

The partially fixed `upload_images()` may look like this:

```
def upload_images():

    # some code skipped 

    def rexists(path):
        try:
            sftp.stat(path)
        except IOError as e:
            if e.errno == errno.ENOENT:
                return False
            raise
        return True

    try:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            for fn in files:
                print 'fn', fn
                ftp_path = '/productimages/' + fn
                archive = '/productimages/archive/' + fn
                source = root + '\\' + fn
                if not rexists(ftp_path):
                    sftp.put(source, ftp_path)
                else:
                    if rexists(archive):
                        sftp.remove(archive)
                    sftp.rename(ftp_path, archive)
                    sftp.put(root + '\\' + fn, ftp_path)

    finally:
        sftp.close()
        ssh.close()
```

however it still fails if `path` contains sub-directories with files.